# Bootstrap- elements overlaps in extra small size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Twitter Bootstrap3. I have a footer section(gray part) and above that is some `divs`. I gave those `divs` `col-xs-12` class to in mobile devices `div` display one after another vertically but the problem is in mobile size, those `divs` place under my footer and even go in the bottom of the page. What is the problem? My code and JsFiddle is following.

HTML:

```
<div id="pre-footer" class="center-block">
            <div class="adv-clickable col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#"><p>تبلیغات کلیکی</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>قوانین</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>آگهی‌دهندگان</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>نمایش دهندگان</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>سوالات متداول</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>هزینه‌ها</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>تسویه حساب با نمایش‌دهندگان</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="adv-clickable col-md-3 col-xs-12 center-block">
                <a href="#"><p>تبلیغات کلیکی</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>قوانین</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>آگهی‌دهندگان</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>نمایش دهندگان</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>سوالات متداول</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>هزینه‌ها</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>تسویه حساب با نمایش‌دهندگان</p></a>
            </div>
            <div id="pre-footer-nested1" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 center-block">
                <img src="images/pre-footer-logo.png">
                <div id="socials">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-telegram"></i></a>
                </div>
                <form action="#" class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">از آخرین اخبار آموزشی و تبلیغاتی با خبر شوید</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="آدرس ایمیل خود را وارد کنید" >
                    <input type="submit" value="ثبت‌نام در خبر نامه" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="pre-footer-nested2" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/nemad.jpg" >
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="col-md-12">
            <p class="color-white">&copy;کپی‌رایت ۱۳۹۶ کسب و کارهای نوپای خاورزمین</p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#pre-footer{
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.adv-clickable{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.adv-clickable a:first-child p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.adv-clickable p{
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.adv-clickable a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pre-footer-nested1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#pre-footer-nested2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
#socials{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#socials i{
    color: #01a89e;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 form{
     margin-top: 20px;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 form label{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 input:last-child{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #01a89e;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 input:last-child:active{
    background-color: #0f8079;
}
#pre-footer-nested2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#pre-footer-nested2 img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
}
#pre-footer-nested2 div{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 22px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.footer-logos{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#footer{
    margin-top: 70px;
    background-color: #333333;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    position: relative;
}
#footer p{
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwwaqq58/2/)
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems breaking your layout:

1. The fixed width of your `#pre-footer`:

```css
#pre-footer { width: 75%; } /* minor problem */
```

2. the `form` element (this is the worst) not wrapping.

You also seem to be using `flexbox` without having documented it much first.

Here's a quick patch for your layout: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/hwwaqq58/4/.

I'd say you need to brush up your CSS or get help from someone who knows more. A few pointers:

1. Don't expect Bootstrap 3 to behave the same when you don't use `.row`s and set `display:flex` on parents of your `.col-*-*` elements, especially if you have non-wrapping content.
2. Adding `display:flex` to everything doesn't really work and is hard to fix, especially if you don't know what each property does.
3. Always place your `.col-*-*`s as direct children of `.row`s.
4. Don't hardcode `height` on `.row`s if you want them to wrap on narrow devices.

Compare your initial CSS with mine and search the properties you don't understand on either W3Schools or MDN, to understand what they do.